# Modify values in an existing table of MS Access using Python

Tags: database, python-2.7, ms-access, pypyodbc

I am trying to change a value of a whole column in MS Access database with python using pypyodbc. 
So far I have only found a way to create a new line but not modify the existing values.

This code is from another question I found and it works but only to create a new line (the table name is Table 1 and the column is Testie not that it really matters)

```
conn=pypyodbc.win_connect_mdb("C:\Users\y.johannes1\Documents\prufa.mdb")
cursor=conn.cursor()
sql= """ INSERT INTO Table1(Testie) Values(10)"""
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()
conn.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use an [UPDATE Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845036.aspx) to change values in existing rows.

Answer (score 4):

This worked if anyone has the same problem

```
conn=pypyodbc.win_connect_mdb("C:\Users\y.johannes1\Documents\prufa.mdb")
cursor=conn.cursor()
sql= """ Update Table1 SET testie=7 WHERE id=1"""
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()
conn.close()
```